# When should I upvote accepted answers to my own questions?

Tags: discussion, voting, etiquette

When should I upvote accepted answers to my own questions?

- Always
- Whenever I would upvote an answer to a stranger's question (for me, that would be the same as "always if I marked the answer as accepted")
- Only if the poster put more than expected effort into the question?
- Never

Is there a general rule? Always and never don't seem to be the correct answer, as those could be automated by the Stack Overflow system...

Comment: @PoolPartyRenekton Those are the various options they're looking at. It makes perfect sense to me. (Note that the _actual_ question, below the bullet points, is not formatted like that. Because it's not an option, and not part of the list of options.)

Comment: Oh i get it now! I wasn't reading the whole question with the title... no wonder it made no sense at the beginning MB @Kendra I'm used to read questions with a bit of intro

Comment: I believe I've seen exactly the same question within the last two days.

Answer (score 12):

When you feel like the answer deserves an upvote.

Votes are, for the most part, yours to do with as you please. If an answer technically answers your question, but you feel like it's poorly written enough not to deserve an upvote, you can accept and not upvote. If it's really poorly written, you can even accept and downvote. If the answerer edits later, you can always either remove your downvote, if you downvoted, or give it a newly-earned upvote.

There is no general rule on this, so do what feels right to you.

Comment: "feels right" - sure, but only when smart reasoning fails you :)

Comment: If "smart reasoning" (who can really judge when someone else's reasoning is "smart"? I'm sure your reasoning seems as smart to you as mine does to me, even if it's completely opposite) is what makes you feel right about upvoting a question, then "smart reasoning" is what you should use. There is _literally_ no guideline on when to upvote an answer you accept- There is a suggestion to accept the answer that helped you most, and there are suggestions for when to upvote, but that's really it. Any user can opt to completely ignore both of those sets of suggestions and vote/accept as they see fit.

Comment: Err... Yes? (I already upvoted your answer, don't waste any further time on me)

Comment: @Gimby That was more meant as a general comment- I forgot it would ping you as the only commenter on the answer thus far. Sorry about the unnecessary ping. (Not wasting time on it was more the reason for waiting so long to comment- More important things to do until now.)

Answer (score 7):

As Kendra notes, you can do whatever you want.  That said, for me, the answer would be "almost always".

In fact, personally, I tend to immediately upvote any answers that seem useful, but wait a while (at least a few hours or days) before accepting any answer, just in case someone else posts an even better one.  (The main exception is when somebody quickly comes up with a *definitive* answer of the "Duh, why didn't I think of that?" type.)  A side effect of doing this is that, typically, the answer I want to accept *will already have an upvote* from me anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Just my biased perspective, but I find it kind of odd when people accept an answer without up-voting it.

I see it that way because we can only accept *one* answer. We can like and up-vote many answers, we can only accept one.

So to accept without up-voting seems weird. It's like, *"Hmm, that answer was good enough to accept but not to vote on?"*

I suppose since voting and accepting an answer are decoupled from each other, one might be tempted to think that both up-voting and accepting is like an extra reward for going above and beyond. People are certainly free to look at it that way.

But I just see it as kind of weird to accept without a vote. Even weirder would be to down-vote and accept. Maybe this could express some kind of reluctant/desperate acceptance of an answer, *"I don't like this answer but I'll take it anyway."*

I don't know -- to me it's much simpler to just up-vote first to express initial approval and accept later to express a favorite.